# How can I select and assign one of many objects using C#?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
   void openPicker(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            var a = sender;
            Picker pkr = sender == ati ? atiPicker : ptiPicker;
            pkr.Focus();
        }
    }
```

The code works good but I need to be able to assign pkr to one of:

```
atiPicker, ptiPiker, noaPicker prtPicker cfsPicker coPicker
```

based on the sender being one of

```
ati, pti, not, prt, cfs or co
```

I think I could do it with many if statements but is there some way that would be better to do this?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` and switch on `ati, pti, not, prt, cfs or co` (Expanding on @mjwills)

Comment: Can you show and example.  Thanks

Comment: What is `ati`? Be aware that depending on that type your `==` may check for reference-equality, making two instances of a class unequal even if all their properties are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void openPicker(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (sender != null)
     {
         var a = sender;
         Picker pkr = sender == ati ? atiPicker : ptiPicker;
         pkr.Focus();
     }
}
```

could be changed to:

```
Dictionary<object, Picker> bob = new Dictionary<object, Picker>() { { ati, atiPicker}, { pti, ptiPicker }};

void openPicker(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (sender != null)          
     {
         var a = sender;
         Picker pkr = bob[sender];
         pkr.Focus();
     }
}
```

*The `Dictionary` allows you to codify the `if` statements into a [hash lookup](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/refactoring-from-if-else-if-to-dictionary) instead.*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you may use a `Dictionary<Type, Func<Picker>>`:

```
var map = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Picker>> { 
    { typeof(ati) }, () => new ATI_Kicker() }, 
    { /* other types */ }}
```

Now you can easily create instances by accessing the value for a given type of `sender`:

```
var picker = map[sender.GetType()]();
picker.Focus();
```

However this allways returns a new instance of the type attached to any of your sender-types every time you query the value for a given key in that map.

Answer (score 1):

Try a switch statement

```
Picker pkr = new Picker();

switch(sender){
    case ati:
        pkr = atiPicker;
        break;
    case pti:
        pkr = ptiPicker;
        break;
    case noa:
        pkr = noaPicker;
        break;
    case prt:
        pkr = prtPicker;
        break;
    case cfs:
        pkr = cfsPicker;
        break;
    case co:
        pkr = coPicker;
        break;
}

pkr.Focus();
```